# How to reduce commit messages by count in github?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to make a sorted list of commit messages by message content in github.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Can you make your question more clear? I don't understand yet.

Comment: Assume that I have 10 commits in my repo, five of the messages are "fix", four are "." and the last one is "added new measuring calculation". I wanna have a table: "fix": 5, ".": 4, "added new measuring calculation": 1.
I want to show my colleagues that relevant messages are important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing so by querying GitHub might be slow and you would need to deal with response pagination.

Cloning the repo locally allows you for a simple [`git log` with pretty format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats):

```
git log --format=%s
```

That focuses on the "subject", meaning the first line of the commit message.

From there you can sort them easily (here the last 100 commits):

```
git log -100 --format=%s | sort  | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

(See more at "[Sorting files by “line content” frequency](https://superuser.com/a/1097812/141)")